# Function not running but not giving syntax error

Tags: autohotkey

- I want to edit a script to make it more automated by taking a compiled piece of code that runs when a certain combination of keyboard hotkeys and just changing it to a function
- My script works but the function that i made doesnt seem to run when it's called(or there might be something wrong with my if statement) but the hotkey version works

original:

```
*+F::
  {
    Loop, %all%
    {
      WinGet, pid, PID, % "ahk_id " all%A_Index%
      WinGetTitle, title, ahk_pid %pid%
      if (InStr(title, "Minecraft*")) {
        WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, ahk_pid %pid%
        WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, ahk_pid %pid%
        WinMaximize, ahk_pid %pid%
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Esc}, ahk_pid %pid%
      }
    }
    Loop, %all%
    {
      WinGet, pid, PID, % "ahk_id " all%A_Index%
      WinGetTitle, title, ahk_pid %pid%
      if (InStr(title, "Minecraft*")) {
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Esc}, ahk_pid %pid%
        StartSettings(pid)
      }
    }
```

my version:

```
startSettingsChange() {
    Loop, %all%
    {
      WinGet, pid, PID, % "ahk_id " all%A_Index%
      WinGetTitle, title, ahk_pid %pid%
      if (InStr(title, "Minecraft*")) {
        WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, ahk_pid %pid%
        WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, ahk_pid %pid%
        WinMaximize, ahk_pid %pid%
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Esc}, ahk_pid %pid%
      }
    }
    Loop, %all%
    {
      WinGet, pid, PID, % "ahk_id " all%A_Index%
      WinGetTitle, title, ahk_pid %pid%
      if (InStr(title, "Minecraft*")) {
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Esc}, ahk_pid %pid%
        StartSettings(pid)
      }
    }
```

I dont really know if I made any mistakes here but I'll add the full code of my edited version and the original

I have a if statement at the end that calls the function if a window title matches a certain state
original:

```
; by Specnr :)
; v0.2

; Startup all instances on title screen, run script, then once all instances are in the world, press Shift+F

#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

SetKeyDelay, 0
SetWinDelay, 1
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

global sprintKey := ""
global perspKey := "T"

StartSettings(pid) {
  ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Shift Down}{F3}{Shift Up}, ahk_pid %pid%
  Sleep, 1000
  ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{1}{1}{1}, ahk_pid %pid%
  ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{%sprintKey%}{%perspKey%}{F3}, ahk_pid %pid%
  Sleep, 1000
  ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{F3 Down}{B}{Esc}{F3 Up}, ahk_pid %pid%
}

WinGet, all, list
Loop, %all%
{
  WinGet, pid, PID, % "ahk_id " all%A_Index%
  WinGetTitle, title, ahk_pid %pid%
  if (InStr(title, "Minecraft*")) {
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Shift down}{Tab}{Shift up}{Enter}, ahk_pid %pid%
  }
}

*+F::
  {
    Loop, %all%
    {
      WinGet, pid, PID, % "ahk_id " all%A_Index%
      WinGetTitle, title, ahk_pid %pid%
      if (InStr(title, "Minecraft*")) {
        WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, ahk_pid %pid%
        WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, ahk_pid %pid%
        WinMaximize, ahk_pid %pid%
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Esc}, ahk_pid %pid%
      }
    }
    Loop, %all%
    {
      WinGet, pid, PID, % "ahk_id " all%A_Index%
      WinGetTitle, title, ahk_pid %pid%
      if (InStr(title, "Minecraft*")) {
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Esc}, ahk_pid %pid%
        StartSettings(pid)
      }
    }
    ExitApp
    return
  }
```

my version:

```
; by Specnr :)
; v0.2

; Startup all instances on title screen, run script, then once all instances are in the world, press Shift+F
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

SetKeyDelay, 0
SetWinDelay, 1
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

global sprintKey := ""
global perspKey := "T"

StartSettings(pid) {
  ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Shift Down}{F3}{Shift Up}, ahk_pid %pid%
  Sleep, 1000
  ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{1}{1}{1}, ahk_pid %pid%
  ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{%sprintKey%}{%perspKey%}{F3}, ahk_pid %pid%
  Sleep, 1000
  ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{F3 Down}{B}{Esc}{F3 Up}, ahk_pid %pid%
}

WinGet, all, list
Loop, %all%
{
  WinGet, pid, PID, % "ahk_id " all%A_Index%
  WinGetTitle, title, ahk_pid %pid%
  if (InStr(title, "Minecraft*")) {
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Shift down}{Tab}{Shift up}{Enter}, ahk_pid %pid%
  }
}

startSettingsChange() {
    Loop, %all%
    {
      WinGet, pid, PID, % "ahk_id " all%A_Index%
      WinGetTitle, title, ahk_pid %pid%
      if (InStr(title, "Minecraft*")) {
        WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, ahk_pid %pid%
        WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, ahk_pid %pid%
        WinMaximize, ahk_pid %pid%
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Esc}, ahk_pid %pid%
      }
    }
    Loop, %all%
    {
      WinGet, pid, PID, % "ahk_id " all%A_Index%
      WinGetTitle, title, ahk_pid %pid%
      if (InStr(title, "Minecraft*")) {
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Blind}{Esc}, ahk_pid %pid%
        StartSettings(pid)
      }
    }


#IfWinActive, Minecraft
{
  WinGetPos, X, Y, W, H, Minecraft
  WinGetTitle, McTitle, Minecraft
  IfNotInString, McTitle, player
  {
       reload
   }
  Else
  {
       startSettingsChange()
   }
} 


    ExitApp
    return
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `all` doesn't exist in that function scope.
If you want to use a variable from outside of that function scope, you need the `global`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Global)</sup> keyword.

```
startSettingsChange() 
{
    global all
    Loop, % all
    {
        ...
```